# How should I normalize gene count data (RNA-seq) for a mixed model with nested and random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, data-transformation, experiment-design, random-effects-model, normalization

**Scenario**:
I have gene count (RNA-seq) data (*VarC*) from a mixed model experimental design that includes nested and random effects (see below).

**Question**: How can I normalize my data based on my experimental design? Is there any R/Python function/package for that?

**Dataset**: Download [here](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-dl0hP2eCHmWDJHUFBQSnJNZk0/view?usp=sharing).

Categorical variables: *VarT*, *VarM*, *VarF*, *VarP*, *VarS*, *VarG*.

Integer variables: *VarC* (gene count, response variable).

*VarM*: Biological replicates of *VarT*.

*VarS*: Biological replicates of VarM+VarF pairs.

*VarP*: Measurement group (samples that were measured together).

**Data structure**:
[image]

**Model**:
I am mostly interested in the effect of *VarT* on *VarC* for each category of *VarG*:

```
Model <- VarC ~ VarT + (1 | VarT:VarM) + (1 | VarF) + (1 | VarP)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize my data"?  Could you give some context?

Comment: How do you want to remove the bias?